# How to run python file with admin rights in pycharm

Tags: python

I'm running this code for trying to ping a server on pycharm:

```
import subprocess as sp

ip = "216.52.241.254"
status,result = sp.getstatusoutput("ping -c1 -w2 " + ip)

if status == 0:
    print("System " + ip + " is UP !")
else:
    print("System " + ip + " is DOWN !")

print(result)
```

However the `print(result)` line always prints `"Access denied. Option -c1 requires administrative privileges."`. I've tried running pycharm as admin but it doesn't have any affect. How can I give admin privileges to the file?

Comment: What OS you're using?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Startup pycharm as Administrator then all scripts will be ran as administrator.

From Windows start menu right click the Pycharm shortcut and select 'Run as administrator.' Optionally create a short and change the options to always Run as Administrator under the "Compatibility" tab.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run the PyCharm shortcut as administrator, and then PyCharm terminal will run with admin privileges.

See these images for referral,

[For Desktop PyCharm Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYD05.png)

[For Start menu search of PyCharm Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py5qX.png)

Answer (score 0):

To run something as `admin` in Windows, you need to execute your application/scrpit from elevated CMD.

So running your python script in `CMD` with `Adiminstrator` privileges should do the work.

Steps:

1. Open `CMD` as Administrator
2. run `python full\path\to\your\script.py`

Now regarding to Windows `ping`:
 `-c` flag is exist only in Linux version of ping. Use `-n` parameter instead for count

Comment: Just tried it running command prompt as admin, I'm getting the same "Access denied" error printed into the command prompt now.

Comment: What is the output of `ping --help`?

Comment: I'm getting a manual, it doesn't seem to include the "c1" command however.

Comment: That's the point :). `-c ` flag is exist only in Linux version of ping. Use `-n` parameter instead for count

Comment: Nice, got it working. Any idea why it seem to recognize c1 as a valid command that needs admin privileges?

Comment: Good question, do you getting the same error if you running `ping -c <ip>`  via command prompt (not via python)?

Comment: Yep, it behaves the same

Comment: Well, looks like a bug to me :)

Answer (score -4):

Change SMTP port to 587 in smtplib.py for gmail use.

SMTP_PORT = 587
SMTP_SSL_PORT = 465

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).